# oracle regexp_replace delete last occurrence of special character

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace

I have a pl sql string as follows :

```
String := 'ctx_ddl.add_stopword(''"SHARK_IDX19_SPL"'',''can''); 

       create index "SCOTT"."SHARK_IDX2"
       on "SCOTT"."SHARK2"
       ("DOC")
          indextype is ctxsys.context
          parameters(''
            datastore       "SHARK_IDX2_DST"
           filter          "SHARK_IDX2_FIL"
           section group   "SHARK_IDX2_SGP"
           lexer           "SHARK_IDX2_LEX"
           wordlist        "SHARK_IDX2_WDL"
           stoplist        "SHARK_IDX2_SPL"
           storage         "SHARK_IDX2_STO"
           sync (every "SYSDATE+(1/1)" memory 67108864)
           '')
           /
       ';
```

I have to get search the final occurrence of '/' and add ';' to it. Also I need to escape the quotes preset in parameters ('') to have extra quotes. I need output like

```
String := 'ctx_ddl.add_stopword(''"SHARK_IDX19_SPL"'',''can''); 

       create index "SCOTT"."SHARK_IDX2"
       on "SCOTT"."SHARK2"
       ("DOC")
          indextype is ctxsys.context
          parameters(''''
            datastore       "SHARK_IDX2_DST"
           filter          "SHARK_IDX2_FIL"
           section group   "SHARK_IDX2_SGP"
           lexer           "SHARK_IDX2_LEX"
           wordlist        "SHARK_IDX2_WDL"
           stoplist        "SHARK_IDX2_SPL"
           storage         "SHARK_IDX2_STO"
           sync (every "SYSDATE+(1/1)" memory 67108864)
           '''')
           /;
       ';
```

Any help.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking here. Please take time to format your question and present it in a clear way so that someone might be able to help you.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do.  Why have you got Oracle Text API calls and DDL statements as strings?  Why are you miing PL/SQL calls and DDL in the same execution space?  If these are scripts why do you want to munge them with REGEXP_REPLACE() instead of editing them with a text editor (perhaps one with regex support)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an age-old saying: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems"

Unless you are confronted by a problem that truly requires regular expressions, I'd recommend working with basic string manipulation functions.

**Semi-colon:**
Use INSTR to find last occurence of '/', call this P1.
Result = Substr from position 1 through P1||';'||substr from P1+1 through to end-of-string

**Parameters substitution:**
Use INSTR to find where parameter list starts (i.e. find "parameters(" in your string) and ends (presumably the last closing parenthesis ")" in your string).  Call these P2 and P3.

Result = substr from 1 through P2 || REPLACE(substr from P2+1 through P3-1,'''','''''''') || substr from P3 to end-of-string